# Selection's background color changes when out of focus

Tags: html, css, selection, background-color, pseudo-element

How do I make the selected text keep its custom background color even if the selection is *"out of focus"*? Just follow these steps in order to better understand what I mean:

1. Select the text
2. Click, for example, in your web browser's search bar

This is the actual output for me:
[image: Selected text with custom background color]
[image: Out of focus selected text with non-custom background color]

**Edit:** The browser I am using is `Firefox 58.0.2`

```css
::selection {
  background-color: red;
}

::-moz-selection {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
```

Comment: I'd say that's a bad practice, the color is different when out of focus so that you can know it, so that if you bash `Ctrl+c` you would know why you didn't get that selected text on the clipboard.

Comment: Following your steps I don't replicate the results you do. What browser are you using?

Comment: its working fine for me https://fiddle.jshell.net/bhuwanb9/Lf2qk5m3/

Comment: @LohmarASHAR Mmmmm... yeah it actually makes sense. I didn't think of that case to be honest.

Comment: @j08691 Sorry, I forgot to add it in the question. It is now there.

Comment: @Bhuwan It might be a browser-specific thing, as the same thing happens to me with your fiddle. What web browser are you using?

Comment: @MikelAlejoBR just checked working fine in chrome but not in firefox

Comment: I checked in `Edge 41.16299.248.0` and the same behavior occurs. It looks that it might be a consciously made decision that has something to do with what @LohmarASHAR said.

Answer (score -1):

You can use two things:

HTML < mark > tag:

```
<mark>Marked text</mark>
```

CSS background color:

```
<p style="background-color: #FFFF00">This complete paragraph of text is highlighted in yellow.</p>
```

Although this is really not advised, as users would like to know when something is selected or not!

Comment: It's not answering the question.